# Check the latency response for both GET and POST of REST API

Tags: c#, rest

I am currently using C#, HttpWebResponse, to call REST API. Is there a way to find out the latency for both GET and POST when invoked?

Comment: Have you tried using a stopwatch?

Comment: the easiest no fuss approach is just time your request with a StopWatch, sure its not latency, yet it will give you an indication all the same

Comment: Use StopWatch to measure the time between you send the request and get the response back.

Comment: hey, has anyone mentioned the Stopwatch class yet?

Comment: Do you mean an increase (or simply, difference) in the time required to perform the same task? A form of latency can caused but a number of factors. The server workload (or the time/bandwidth reserved to you). Topology of the connection, routing. Not disposing of the instantiated objects. I don't know if you can call it latency, but that's what you get. You could use a [StopWatch()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch(v=vs.110).aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396&cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1), anyway (*I have linked it* :).

Comment: @Jonesopolis i think someone should suggest the stopwatch class

Comment: The StopWatch class ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Stopwatch approach

```
void Main()
{
    void TestRequest(string userAgent)
    {
        Stopwatch timer = new Stopwatch();
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://youtube.com");
        request.UserAgent = userAgent;

        timer.Start();
        using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
        {
            Console.WriteLine(timer.Elapsed);
            timer.Stop();
        }
    }
    
    string mobileWin8UserAgent = @"Mozilla/5.0 (Mobile; Windows Phone 8.1; Android 4.0; ARM; Trident/7.0; Touch; rv:11.0; IEMobile/11.0; NOKIA; Lumia 520) like iPhone OS 7_0_3 Mac OS X AppleWebKit/537 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile Safari/537";
    string netscape3UserAgent = @"Mozilla/3.0 (Win95; I)";
    
    TestRequest(mobileWin8UserAgent);
    TestRequest(netscape3UserAgent);
}
```

---

## Fiddler approach

Fiddler is a reverse proxy, it allows you to see not only the exact requests flying out and the responses coming back in, but also stats and much much more.

[image: Fiddler]